# LINQ to Object comparing two lists of integer for different values

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

> I accept both C# and VB.NET suggestion, even though I'm writing an app in VB.NET

I have two lists of intergers

- List1 {1,2,3,5}
- List2 {2,4,6,7}

I want to have new List3 {4,6,7} which is composed of elements of List2 that are not in List1. I know I can write a nice For Each loop for this but I want it done in LINQ
I've been looking for such methods at [Enumerable Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), but I can't find it.

Is there any way to do with LINQ?

Comment: It's right there in the doc you were reading. Check Except methods.

Comment: Does the order of the output matter? Do you want to preserve duplicates?

Comment: I don't want to preserve the duplicates. Yes, the order of output matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
List2.Except(List1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var List3 = List2.Except(List1);
```